# sqlite3 command line parameters from Terminal on the Mac

Tags: command-line, sqlite

I am trying to automate some scripts.  Right now, I do:

```
sqlite3 testDB < mySqlScript.sql
```

I need to run this script multiple times, just changing my TableName in the script.  So instead of manually doing

```
CREATE TABLE sometableXXX
insert into someTableXXX
```

I'd like to be able to pass something into mySqlScripts.sql so I can automatically insert that value in for

```
someTableXXX
```

is that possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the whole SQL code different or just only the table name? Then I whould do something like this:

```
for i in tableName1 tableName2 tableName3 etc ; do
    sed -e "s/someTableXXX/${i}/g" mySqlScript.sql | sqlite3 testDB
done
```

Comment: just the tableName is different

Comment: I basically am manually copying and pasting the same script over and over and just manually changing the tableName in my script.

Comment: if only the table name changes the use `sed` like I suggested

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Do I put that for loop in another file?  I'm running my script from the command line doing: sqlite3 testDB < mysSqlScript.sql

Comment: Do you know bash? What I've writen is a bash script, you can either put it on a separte file or copy & paste it in a console terminal.

my script does exactly that what your doing manually.